# Ensure correct write-back of SharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-file, android-framework, performance

I'm using SharedPreferences to persists Object fields. Take this example:

```
class Item {

    private String note;

    public void setNote(String newNote) {
        this.note = newNote;
        update();
    }

    private void update() {
        String json = ....; // create JSON image of the object

        Editor editor = App.getAppPrefs().edit(); // Load SharedPreferences editor
        editor.putString("exampleItem", json);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

setNote() (and thus update()) is called everytime a "Note"-EditText is changed.

Now I have several questions: How can I verify that the newest version of "note" is saved? Is the possibility that the last call is overriden by an earlier call to editor? How can I minimize the workload? There has to be some smarter, lighter way than calling apply() 100x for a 100 char text.

Comment: How about you set a flag, and if the user has not typed for more than a few seconds then save? The save should be almost instant, but unless you need to save on every char a user writes, then just do it periodically.

Comment: This is an excellent idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `synchronized` it will help thread to wait until old thread complete its work for update.

```
private synchronized void update() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use editor.commit();
Moreover to check that the newest version of the note is saved, you can remove the previous version and then save the new note.
Then based on your need you can either use Toast message or an syso.

Comment: I don't quite get your point @Deepak. When editor.putX() always overwrites, why shall I remove the previous version first? And how can I check if the last version has been saved and not been compromised by another write attempt?